# How to restore a MySQL file to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have a MySQL file (apple.sql) that I need to restore to a SQL server 2008 database or at least be able to access the database through mySQL. I have created a linked server mySQL, created an empty database on mySQL. I am not sure how to restore the backup file (apple.sql) to the empty database?? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should [download and install MySQL MSI on the Windows machine](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

By default, root@localhost has no password

Once mysqld.exe appears in the Taks Manager's process list, run the following

```
C:\> net start mysql
C:\> mysql -uroot -e"CREATE DATABASE apple"
C:\> mysql -uroot -Dapple < apple.sql
```

Database will be loaded in MySQL

You can check everything afterwards. First, login to mysql

```
C:\> mysql -uroot
```

Then run these client commands

```
mysql> use apple
mysql> show tables
```

You can set up DTS or any other mechanism for migrating from MySQL to SQL Server